# Efficient Implementation of Linear Transformation Game using Segmentation Tree (segtree)

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, logic

people, how are you? I am facing a strange issue dealing with the problem below and its implementation. Could you help me? Do you think it could be a error on the update function?

**Problem**:

In the city of Nlogonia, children play a game involving linear transformations on points drawn on a sheet of paper. The game consists of n time instants, each associated with a linear transformation. Points are "born" at time t0, undergo transformations, and "die" at time td. The goal is to determine the point's position at its death, given birth time, death time, initial coordinates, and transformations. Linear transformations are represented by 2×2 matrices, initially all identity matrices.

Children can perform two operations: 1. Update: Change the transformation matrix at a specific time instant. 2. Lookup: Given birth and death times and initial coordinates, determine the final coordinates of the point at its death. To efficiently handle these operations, a segmentation tree (segtree) data structure is proposed.

To implement the segtree, three functions are required: 1. Building a segtree. 2. Performing queries. 3. Performing updates. The segtree enables quick computation of both query and update operations by precomputing solutions for subarrays.

Input is read from standard input, starting with two integers, n and q, indicating the number of time instants and operations. Subsequent lines describe operations in order: 1. Update: "u" followed by a time instant (a), and two lines with 2 integers each representing the new transformation matrix. 2. Query: "q" followed by four integers t0, td, x, and y, representing birth and death instants and initial coordinates. The output should be two integers, the coordinates at which the point disappears, with only the 8 least significant digits printed.

**My code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MOD 100000000

typedef struct {
    long long int m[2][2];
} Matrix;

typedef struct {
    Matrix val;
    int lazy;
} Node;

Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    Matrix result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            result.m[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
                result.m[i][j] += (a.m[i][k] * b.m[k][j]) % MOD;
                result.m[i][j] %= MOD;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void build(Node *tree, Matrix *arr, int start, int end, int current) {
    if (start == end) {
        tree[current].val = arr[start];
        tree[current].lazy = 0;
        return;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    build(tree, arr, start, mid, 2 * current + 1);
    build(tree, arr, mid + 1, end, 2 * current + 2);

    tree[current].val = multiply(tree[2 * current + 1].val, tree[2 * current + 2].val);
    tree[current].lazy = 0;
}

void update(Node *tree, int start, int end, int left, int right, int current, Matrix matrix) {
    if (tree[current].lazy != 0) {
        Matrix lazyMatrix;
        lazyMatrix.m[0][0] = 1;
        lazyMatrix.m[0][1] = 0;
        lazyMatrix.m[1][0] = 0;
        lazyMatrix.m[1][1] = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tree[current].lazy; ++i) {
            lazyMatrix = multiply(lazyMatrix, matrix);
        }

        tree[current].val = multiply(tree[current].val, lazyMatrix);

        if (start != end) {
            tree[2 * current + 1].lazy += tree[current].lazy;
            tree[2 * current + 2].lazy += tree[current].lazy;
        }

        tree[current].lazy = 0;
    }

    if (start > right || end < left) {
        return;
    }

    if (start >= left && end <= right) {
        tree[current].val = multiply(tree[current].val, matrix);

        if (start != end) {
            tree[2 * current + 1].lazy += 1;
            tree[2 * current + 2].lazy += 1;
        }

        return;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    update(tree, start, mid, left, right, 2 * current + 1, matrix);
    update(tree, mid + 1, end, left, right, 2 * current + 2, matrix);

    tree[current].val = multiply(tree[2 * current + 1].val, tree[2 * current + 2].val);
}

Matrix query(Node *tree, int start, int end, int left, int right, int current) {
    if (tree[current].lazy != 0) {
        Matrix lazyMatrix;
        lazyMatrix.m[0][0] = 1;
        lazyMatrix.m[0][1] = 0;
        lazyMatrix.m[1][0] = 0;
        lazyMatrix.m[1][1] = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tree[current].lazy; ++i) {
            lazyMatrix = multiply(lazyMatrix, tree[current].val);
        }

        tree[current].val = multiply(tree[current].val, lazyMatrix);

        if (start != end) {
            tree[2 * current + 1].lazy += tree[current].lazy;
            tree[2 * current + 2].lazy += tree[current].lazy;
        }

        tree[current].lazy = 0;
    }

    if (start > right || end < left) {
        Matrix identity;
        identity.m[0][0] = 1;
        identity.m[0][1] = 0;
        identity.m[1][0] = 0;
        identity.m[1][1] = 1;
        return identity;
    }

    if (start >= left && end <= right) {
        return tree[current].val;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Matrix leftResult = query(tree, start, mid, left, right, 2 * current + 1);
    Matrix rightResult = query(tree, mid + 1, end, left, right, 2 * current + 2);

    return multiply(leftResult, rightResult);
}

int main() {
    int n, q;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    Matrix *matrices = malloc(n * sizeof(Matrix));
    Node *tree = malloc(4 * n * sizeof(Node)); // Assuming a complete binary tree

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matrices[i].m[0][0] = 1;
        matrices[i].m[0][1] = 0;
        matrices[i].m[1][0] = 0;
        matrices[i].m[1][1] = 1;
    }

    build(tree, matrices, 0, n - 1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i) {
        char operation;
        scanf(" %c", &operation);

        if (operation == 'u') {
            int time;
            scanf("%d", &time);

            Matrix newMatrix;
            scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld", &newMatrix.m[0][0], &newMatrix.m[0][1], &newMatrix.m[1][0], &newMatrix.m[1][1]);

            update(tree, 0, n - 1, time - 1, time - 1, 0, newMatrix);
        } else if (operation == 'q') {
            int t0, td, x, y;
            scanf("%d %d %d %d", &t0, &td, &x, &y);

            Matrix result = query(tree, 0, n - 1, t0 - 1, td - 1, 0);
            long long int newX = (result.m[0][0] * x + result.m[0][1] * y) % MOD;
            long long int newY = (result.m[1][0] * x + result.m[1][1] * y) % MOD;

            printf("%lld %lld\n", newX, newY);
        }
    }

    free(matrices);
    free(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### **Examples of failed cases**:

--- Input ---

```
3 6
u 0
0 1
1 0
q 0 2 5 7
u 2
0 1
1 0
q 0 2 5 7
u 2
42 397
1048 32
q 0 2 5 7
```

--- Program output ---

```
5 7
7 5
5464 2989
```

--- Expected output (numbers)---

```
7 5
5 7
5464 2989
```

---

--- Input ---

```
2 4
u 0
17 0
0 17
u 1
5882353 0
0 5882353
q 0 1 1 0
q 0 1 0 1
```

--- Program output ---

```
5882353 0
0 5882353
```

--- Expected output (numbers)---

```
1 0
0 1
```

---

--- Input ---

```
3 5
u 0
0 1
0 0
u 1
0 0
0 1
u 2
0 1
0 0
q 0 1 0 1
q 1 2 0 1
```

--- Program output ---

```
0 1
0 0
```

--- Expected output (numbers)---

```
1 0
0 0
```

Comment: looks like all the stuff having to do with `lazy` is incorrect and unnecessary.

Comment: @Everson Elias Gonalves de Oliv – 
Why is your _Expected output_ for the first example's third query _`5464 2989`_?

Comment: Indeed besides other errors I _think it could be a error on the update function_; the result of the update depends on previous updates of the same node, while it shouldn't - the tree after an update should rather be the same as after a new build with the new matrix.